# speeding up dictionary (list) processing in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary list of size ~250k in python (i.e 250k dictionaries in a list), which I try to process as shown below. The aim is to `clean up` the dictionary and return an iterable at the end. So, I have something like this:

```
def check_qs(dict_list_in):
    try:
        del_id=[]
        for i in dict_list_in:
            tmp=i["get_url"][0]
            if i["from"][0]=="var0":
                try:
                    URLValidator()(tmp)
                except:
                    del_id.append( i["id"] )
            elif i["from"][0]=="var1":
                try:
                    URLValidator()( tmp.split("\"")[1] )
                except:
                    del_id.append( i["id"] )
            elif i["from"][0]=="var2":
                try:
                    URLValidator()( tmp.split("\'")[1] )
                except:
                    del_id.append( i["id"] )
            else:
                del_id.append( i["id"] )
            gc.collect()
        result = filter(lambda x: x['id'] not in del_id,dict_list_in)
        return result
     except:
        return dict_list_in
```

What I am doing above, is checking each dictionary in ths list for some condition, and if this `fails`, I get the `id` and then use `filter` to delete those dictionaries specific from the list.

At the moment, this takes a long time to run - and I was wondering if there were any obvious optimizations I am missing out on. I think at the moment the above code is too naive.

Comment: What is `qs`? I don't see you define it before you use it

Comment: Please do read [Why is "except: pass" a bad programming practice?](//stackoverflow.com/q/21553327); don't use blanket `except:` statements. Catch specific exceptions *only*.

Comment: You have a straight-forward loop here otherwise. If this is slow, it'll be the `URLValidator()()` calls, not the  list processing. **Isolate** your components and test them for performance individually, or use a proper profiler to identify the bottlenecks.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh: Sorry, I have corrected this now - it should have been `dict_list_in` (changed variable names to make it more obvious!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a couple changes. I put the validation instance out of the loop so that you don't have to initialize it every time. If it's required to instantiate every time, just move it into the try accept block. I also changed from deleting items in the original list, to appending the items to a new list that you want, removing the need for a filter. I also moved the validation out of the if statements so that if you hit the else statement you don't have to run the validation. Look at the logic of the if statements, it is the same as yours. It appears that you are using django, but if you aren't change the `except` to `except Exception`.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def check_qs(dict_list_in):
    new_dict_list = []
    validate = URLValidator()

    for i in dict_list_in:
        test_url = i["get_url"][0]
        if i["from"][0] == "var0":
            pass
        elif i["from"][0] == "var1":
            test_url = test_url.split("\"")[1]
        elif i["from"][0] == "var2":
            test_url = test_url.split("\'")[1]
        else:
            continue

        try:
            validate(test_url)
        # If you aren't using django you can change this to 'Exception'
        except ValidationError:
            continue
        new_dict_list.append(i)

    return new_dict_list
```